# How many JavaScript event handlers is too many?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I'm writing a PHP/jQuery application, and I'm wondering how many event handlers is too many?

For example in my main .js file I have roughly fifteen

```
$('body').on('click','.someElementClass',function(){
    someFunction();
});
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this / what is the best practice for this?

Edit: 'body' above is just an example, I AM binding to the deepest element I can.

Comment: If your DOM isn't going to be changing between full page loads `$('.someElementClass').click(fn)` will be faster.

Comment: I came here asking the same question so I disagree with "closed as not constructive". Thanks for asking it!

Answer (score 3):

If your application fits the performance requirements - then it's not too many. If it doesn't - then it's too many. That simple.

Answer (score 3):

> *"Is there a better way to accomplish this / what is the best practice for this?"*

Yes there's a better way. Right now you're binding all click activity to a single container.

This means that every `.someElementClass`, needs to be invoked for every click on the page, and in fact multiple times because the event bubbles.

The proper way would be to bind the handlers to the most deeply nested container that encompasses each given selector. That way each handler is only invoked for clicks inside that part of the page.

> *"I'm wondering how many event handlers is too many?"*

Naturally this will depend on the requirements of the application, but using the approach described above will make the presence of multiple handlers less of a concern.

Comment: Edited my original post. I am binding to the deepest element possible, body was just an example.

Comment: @Nick: Well that would radically change the question.